# Python/Selenium automation email question

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I am completely new to development and automation so I've been playing around with Python and Selenium to fill out simple forms. The form I am using will detect existing email addresses in a Database so I need to know how to tell the program to use a unique email address on each automation test start. In this case, the email I want to use is huks214+(Randomvalue)@gmail.com and have that random value change each time I run the script. Below is a code snipit from Selenium

```
driver.find_element_by_id("Email_Address").send_keys("jhfggf@kjkj.com")
driver.find_element_by_id("Cnfm_Email_Address").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("Cnfm_Email_Address").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("Cnfm_Email_Address").send_keys("jhfggf@kjkj.com")
```

This is inputting the email address as I entered it on the form when I recorded it. I have the below code which will change the email address but I'm unsure on how to integrate it into the above script

```
import string
import random
email = 'huks214+' + ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(10)) + '@gmail.com'
print (email)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the generated value instead of a hardcoded string. Extracting the email generation code into a function would also be a good idea:

```
import string
import random


def generate_email(prefix='huks214+', domain='gmail.com'):
    random_part = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) 
                          for _ in range(10))

    return prefix + random_part + '@' + domain


# your code that defines driver here
email = generate_email()

driver.find_element_by_id("Email_Address").send_keys(email)
confirm_email = driver.find_element_by_id("Cnfm_Email_Address")
confirm_email.click()
confirm_email.clear()
confirm_email.send_keys(email)
```